# Finding an Object's value from an Array

Tags: javascript

Is there a simpler (or more efficient) way of achieving the following:

```
var _dataObjects = [{id:0, data:"data0", nextID:1}, 
                    {id:1, data:"data1", nextID:2}, 
                    {id:2, data:"data2", nextID:3} .. etc.];
generateNextPieceOfData();

function generateNextPieceOfData(){
    var len = _dataObjects.length;
    for ( var i = 0; i < len; i ++ ) {
        var nextDataID = _dataObjects[i].nextID;
        var nextData;
        for ( var j = 0; j < len; j ++ ) {
            if( _dataObjects[j].id == nextDataID ){
                nextData = _dataObjects[j].data;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above example is abstracted from the problem I'm having and I realise the ID numbers are sequential in this instance but in the real problem `nextID` numbers do not run sequentially.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the code do? What is its purpose? Is it supposed to return anything, because it does not seem to do anything useful.

Comment: The code will eventually decide a path between nodes in 3D space based on the id and nextID values. As I mentioned in my question, the example code above is abstract but is representative of my problem so it won't do anything useful. If I were to post the problem with full context it would be superfluous.

Comment: Yeah, but it would still more useful to let the function have a proper input and output. Can I assume that you pass it two IDs and finding the path means to find all objects from the first ID to the second ID (following `nextID`)? In any case, if you use an object has hash map, where the IDs are the keys and the objects are the values, you can easily find the next object.

Comment: find last next id, last nextdata all the time and not necessarily related ones. and even those r local variables..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the right data structure for your problem. Since you want to find an object by ID, create a hash map with the IDs as keys and objects as values:

```
var object_map = {};

for(var i = 0, l = _dataObjects.length; i < l; i++) {
    objects[_dataObjects[i].id] = _dataObjects[i];
}
```

Then getting the next object is simply:

```
var next_object = object_map[someObject.nextID];
```

You still have iterate until some terminal condition is met though. For example:

```
function generatePath(id_a, id_b) {
    var obj = object_map[id_a];
    var path = [obj];

    while (obj && obj.id !== id_b) {
        obj = object_map[obj.nextID];
        path.push(obj);
    }
    return path;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your code works sequentially only, then you can `sort` the items by `id` or whatever and your code should work right? Try this:

```
_dataObjects = _dataObjects.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.id > b.id;
});
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking your time to answer but: "The above example is abstracted from the problem I'm having and I realise the ID numbers are sequential in this instance but in the real problem nextID numbers do not run sequentially."

Comment: ??? This already _assumes_ that your `_dataObjects` array is not ordered sequentially. Have you tried the code?

Comment: I did, but I didn't explain my problem very I apologise and this just wasn't what I needed. Thanks for helping though.